# Gradle build error in eclipse: Could not find or load main class Files\OpenJdk11\lib\security\cacerts

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I tried to import a gradle project into eclipse workspace and selected

> Gradle -> Refresh dependencies

But, I am seeing the following error in the error log

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.3-bin.zip'.
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\OpenJdk11\bin\java.exe --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\OpenJdk11\lib\security\cacerts" -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\raviteja.kothapalli\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.3-bin\71q0cerxks9z090hthk8vq8r7\gradle-5.6.3\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.3.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.6.3
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\OpenJdk11\lib\security\cacerts
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\OpenJdk11\lib\security\cacerts   my-project line 0   Gradle Error Marker
```

From the last line, it sounds like the gradle vm is somehow unable to understand the space between "Program Files" folder and hence giving the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\OpenJdk11\lib\security\cacerts`

Note: The build is successful through command line though.

These are the gradle settings in eclipse

[image]

Comment: So does it work when you copy your _OpenJdk11_ to a directory with a path without spaces?

Comment: @howlger, no. it doesn't. I believe the location is being picked up from the path variable. somehow this is not changing even after changing the path in the system "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\OpenJdk11\lib\security\cacerts"

Comment: In which error log do you see the error? The error log of Eclipse? If yes, please show it starting with `!SESSION` and tell with which Java do you run Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger, the error is seen in the "Problems" section of eclipse. I copied the exception by Right click -> Copy

Comment: @howlger, I also checked the eclipse logs and I see `java.version=17.0.1`. However, I have OpenJdk11 installed in my box. Not sure how this version is being picked up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by manually adding a vm argument to the gradle configuration of the project like this ("C:\Program Files" still didn't work. I had to change the location to another location without spaces in the name).

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="D:\OpenJdk11\lib\security\cacerts"
```